# Are there predefined functions in scipy/numpy to shift/rotate an image that use sinc-interpolation instead of spline interpolation?

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, scipy, image-rotation

The question title summarizes it well I hope. I have a large batch of images which I want to register. For this purpose I need to shift/rotate the images. So far I have used scipy.ndimage.rotate and scipy.ndimage.shift for this task. However, some of the images have sharp intensity features for which the higher order spline interpolation fails (i.e. produces ringing artefacts). Lower order (0 or 1) splines are not preserving the image data well enough.

Is there a build in task in scipy/numpy (or any other package in principle) that uses sinc interpolation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker%E2%80%93Shannon_interpolation_formula)?

I have searched around for quiet a while myself but have not come up with any easy solutions, if I have missed something obvious please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using the command line `convert` from [imageMagik](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#interpolate) you can convert the entire batch and have control of the interpolation method - available methods are:

> integer - The color of the top-left pixel (floor function).
>
> nearest-neighbor - The nearest pixel to the lookup point (rounded function)
>
> average     -     The average color of the surrounding four pixels
>
> bilinear   -     A double linear interpolation of pixels (the default)
>
> mesh       -      Divide area into two flat triangular interpolations
>
> bicubic    -      Fitted bicubic-spines of surrounding 16 pixels
>
> spline     -      Direct spline curves (colors are blurred)
>
> filter      -     Use resize-filter settings

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I would prefer a native python solution if possible, also if I am not missing something (which is possible) these interpolation methods do also not include a sinc interpolation